# having trouble with square root loop using python

Tags: python, loops, square-root

i have a user input 'n' and i am finding the square root. Which i know is math.sqrt(n), but i need to make the program continue find the square root until it is less than 2. also return to the user how many times the program ran to find the root less than 2 using a counter. I am using python.

So far:

```
import math
root = 0
n = input('Enter a number greater than 2 for its root: ')

square_root = math.sqrt(n)
print 'The square root of', n, 'is', square_root

keep_going = 'y'

while keep_going == 'y':
    while math.sqrt(n) > 2:
        root = root + 1
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: You should put your code into your original question. This will make it readable, especially given python's use of indentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
user_in = input()
num = int(user_in)

num = math.sqrt(num)
count = 1
while(num > 2):
  num = math.sqrt(num)
  count += 1

print count
```

Comment: why would you solve people's homework like that... in 3 years he'll be sitting in a cubicle next to yours...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2.x

```
count = 0
user_input = int(raw_input("enter:"))
while true:    
    num = math.sqrt( user_input )
    if num < 2: break
    print num
    count+=1
print count
```

Error checking for user input not present.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious way:

```
def sqrtloop(n):
    x = 0
    while n >= 2:
        n **= 0.5
        x += 1
    return x
```

Not that much:

```
def sqrtloop2(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 0
    return math.floor(math.log(math.log(n, 2), 2)) + 1
```

Comment: Note that the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that you should use spaces around augmented assignments (**=, +=), comparisons (<) and assignment (=) (except in function argument lists when defining defaults). Also, you should _rather_ _not_ write compound statements on one line, like `if n < 2: return 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
num = 0
while num < 100:
   
   num_sqrt = num ** 0.5
   print('The square root of %0.3f is %0.3f'%(num ,num_sqrt))
   
   num = num + 1
print ("Good bye!")
```